# Omega needed, if all elements span one column?

Tags: compass-sass, sass, susy-compass

If all elements span exactly one column, can [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net) *automatically* (without specifying `omega`) fill a multi column layout?

What I *want*:

```
+---------+---------+
| I       | want    |
+---------+---------+
| two     | columns |
+---------+---------+
```

What I *get* (code below):

```
+---------+
| I       |
+---------+
| want    |
+---------+
| two     |
+---------+
| columns |
+---------+
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>I</div>
  <div>want</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>columns!</div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```css
@import 'susy';

$total-columns: 2;
$column-width: 200px;
$gutter-width: 5px;
$grid-padding: 10px;

#container {
    @include container;
    @include susy-grid-background;

    &>div {
        @include span-columns(1);
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need to specify omega, because otherwise Susy would have to assume too many things about your markup and desired outcome. We try to avoid that at all costs. The best way to solve this is to use the `nth-omega()` mixin:

```
div {
  @include span-columns(1);
  @include nth-omega(even);
}
```

It's a simple extension of the `:nth-child()` selector, and takes the same keywords, numbers, or algorithms.

Comment: I also tried with three columns: `nth-omega('3n')` Works great!

Comment: Now let's make things more complex. In [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453899/omega-if-elements-have-different-widths) I ask what to do if elements have different widths.