# Omega if elements have different widths?

Tags: compass-sass, sass, susy-compass

**Can [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net) automatically fill a multi column layout if elements have
different widths?**

What I *want* (see code below):

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| I       | want    | this    |
+---------+---------+---------+
| filled  | automatically!    |
+---------+-------------------+
```

What I *get* (see code below):

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| I       | want    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
| this    | filled  |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
| automatically!    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

*Purpose?* For a responsive layout, it should be possible to switch to two
columns for smaller screens (media query breakpoint):

```
+---------+---------+
| I       | want    |
+---------+---------+
| this    | filled  |
+---------+---------+
| automatically!    |
+-------------------+
```

This can be implemented simply by letting all elements float left.
However, I would like to use something like Susy to reduce complexity.

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">I</div>
  <div class="one">want</div>
  <div class="one">this</div>
  <div class="one">filled</div>
  <div class="two">automatically</div>
</div>
```

SCSS, without Omega and not working:

```css
@import 'susy';

$total-columns: 3;
$column-width: 200px;
$gutter-width: 5px;
$grid-padding: 10px;

#container {
    @include container;
    @include susy-grid-background;

    &>div {
        height: 50px;
    }

    &>div.one {
        @include span-columns(1);
    }

    &>div.two {
        @include span-columns(2);
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susy has the `at-breakpoint()` mixin for establishing different column-counts at different media-query breakpoints. But no, you can't do it *automatically*.

Comment: Thanks for clarification that this cannot be done automatically. Using media query breakpoints to solve the problem would mean that I have to add information about which element is the last in a row in three column layout. For two column layout, it can be done automatically, simply with `&>div.one { @include span-columns(1); @include nth-omega(even); }`.